# Is there a one liner for this?

Tags: ruby, refactoring, ruby-2.0

Assuming `search` is expensive, is there a way to make this a one liner?

```
result = Product.search(query)
return result if result
```

Since the search is expensive, the following is out:

```
return Product.search(query) if Product.search(query)
```

Comment: `if result = Product.search(query) then return result end` Just curious, why does this need to be a one-liner?

Comment: @Joe cause this particular method has many exit paths and it'd be nice to see them stacked. return a if x; return b if y; etc.

Comment: @Joe why not make that a possible answer?

Comment: Can you do just `return result if (result = Product.search(query))` ?

Comment: @mbratch Looks like it. Make it an answer man!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
result = Product.search(query) and return result
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution (Ruby 1.9+):

```
Product.search(query).tap {|result| return result if result }
```

But I dont think this makes the code any clear. I would prefer to write something like:

```
if result = Product.search(query)
  return result
end
```

Comment: Didn't consider option #2 for some reason. That's less ugly than what I have right now. Nice. A clear one-liner would still be even nicer though. Where's the ruby magic!? :)

Answer (score 1):

One possibility:

```
if result = Product.search(query) then return result end
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not

```
return Product.search(query)
```

In your example

```
result = Product.search(query)
return result if result
```

you do not define, what should be returned, if result is false/nil. My solution just return this false/nil.

Alternative:

```
return Product.search(query) || 'Sorry no result'
```

If you have alternative code after the reutrn, you may use

```
return Product.search(query) || other_method_to_get_result
```

`other_method_to_get_result` is a method with another search - or whatever you normally have after your `return`.

Answer (score 0):

If it does not depend what gets returned, you simple can make a one-line like this:

```
return Product.search(query)
```